# pip. Установка, Апгрейд

Tags: python, pip

Пытаюсь установить `psutil`, но нужно обновить `pip`.

Делал следующие:

```
C:\Users\Антон\Desktop\uroki>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/74/ecd13431bcc456ed390b44c8a6e917c1820365cbebcb6a8974d1cd045ab4/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 573kB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 9.0.3
    Uninstalling pip-9.0.3:
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка:

```
ou are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

При этом на работе мне помогла перестановка `python` в режиме `modify`.
А дома не прокатывает. 
Брал последнюю версию `python`.

Comment: Самое главное и нужное — содержимое Exception — взяли и не написали

Comment: Да и psutil входит в стандартную библиотеку. Зачем его устанавливать?

Comment: пытаюсь вставить exeption, мне пишут что это код и его нужно оформить как следует. чет не получается.

Comment: поправил, тупо сделал принскрин.
ребят, я только учусь программировать, поэтому нифига не понимаю.

Comment: Запустите cmd от имени администратора и эта проблема уйдёт.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал переустановить Python не в program files - проблем меньше будет.

Comment: Сергей Горностаев, просто респектище Вам!!! заработало!!!

Comment: Insolur, при переустановке накосячил, сам только что увидел что вообще в корень программ файлс установило. а куда лучше устанавливать?

Comment: @Антон, в `C:\Python` просто установите. В корень `Program files` ставить - это вообще странное решение.

Comment: @insolor, да я как-то по умолчанию устанавливал. Хорошо, переустановлю.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev psutil не входит в стандартную библиотеку.

Comment: ошибку лучше как текст приводить в вопросе (с форматированием как код), а не как картинку, чтобы люди с похожей проблемой могли найти этот вопрос (к примеру по фразе pip install и "отказано в доступе")

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev я что-то не догнал как вставить с форматированием кода.